# Upload excel file using angularjs to sql table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am trying to make a contact module in sql server 2008 r2, where I have created some table for keeping contact info of the business entities. I want to create a front end using angularjs using which I can upload a single file(excel) at a time and save all the info to database. Is there any good approach using angularjs?.

Comment: Please be little bit clear here, so i mean do you want to save all contacts into db by picking up them from the file or you want to upload only that file containing contacts.

Comment: I do have some contacts maintained in Excel file which I want to upload everytime to save all the records to db.

Comment: ever got an answer to this ?

Comment: **Sana** Not yet.